# Find the reaction of the table

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, rotations, classical-mechanics

> A uniform rod of mass $m$ and length $2a$ is held inclined to the vertical at an angle $\alpha$ with its lower end in contact with a smooth horizontal table and is released from rest. Prove that when the inclination of the rod to the vertical is $\theta$, the reaction of the table is
> $$\frac{mg(4-6\cos{\alpha}\cos{\theta}+3\sin^2{\theta})}{(1+3\sin^2{\theta})^2} $$

I got reaction of the table as $\dfrac{mg(4-6\cos{\alpha}\cos{\theta}+3\cos^2{\theta})}{(1+3\sin^2{\theta})^2} $ which is not what we need to prove but I think my answer is correct, If $\alpha=0$ and $\theta=0$ then rod is vertical so reaction must be $mg$ which is satisfy my answer but $\dfrac{mg(4-6\cos{\alpha}\cos{\theta}+3\sin^2{\theta})}{(1+3\sin^2{\theta})^2} $ is not satisfied

Can anyone help me for this? Am I correct?

Comment: Is the rod held by an end or at middle or...?

Comment: @Ripi2 It doesn't a matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same result as you.

The motion of the rod can be understood as translation of the center od mass (midpoint of rod) and rotation around the center of mass. As there are no horizontal forces acting on the center of mass, the center of mass only moves vertically. If we denote its height by $y$, the conservation of energy gives
$$\frac12 m\dot{y} + \frac12 I\omega^2 + mgy = mgy(0).$$
where the moment of inertia is $I = \frac{ma^2}3$ and $\omega = \dot{\theta}$ is angular rotation around the center of mass. We can note that $y = a\cos\theta$ so $\dot{y} = -a\omega\sin\theta$. Plugging this in we get
$$\frac12ma^2\omega^2\sin^2\theta + \frac16ma^2\omega^2 + mga\cos\theta=mga\cos\alpha $$
which implies
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{6g(\cos\alpha - \cos\theta)}{a(1+3\sin^2\theta)}}.$$

Now, since the table is smooth, the reaction force $\vec{N}$ acts only upwards. Its projection orthogonally to the rod is $N\sin\theta$. The resulting torque $Na\sin\theta$ drives the rotation of the rod. The rotational equation of motion is
$$N\sin\theta = I\dot{\omega}.$$
After some calculation, we get
$$\dot\omega = \sqrt{\frac{6g}{a}} \frac1{2\sqrt{\frac{\cos\alpha - \cos\theta}{1+3\sin^2\theta}}}\frac{(4-6\cos\alpha\cos\theta +3\cos^2\theta)\sin\theta}{2(1+3\sin^2\theta)^2} \omega = \frac{3g(4-6\cos\alpha\cos\theta +3\cos^2\theta)\sin\theta}{2a(1+3\sin^2\theta)^2}$$
so
$$N = I\frac{\dot\omega}{\sin\theta} = \frac{ma^2}3\frac{3g(4-6\cos\alpha\cos\theta +3\cos^2\theta)}{2a(1+3\sin^2\theta)^2} = \frac{mg(4-6\cos\alpha\cos\theta +3\cos^2\theta)}{(1+3\sin^2\theta)^2}.$$

Comment: If I plug $\alpha=0$ and $\theta=0$ should it be $mg$?

Comment: @noname Yes, I would certainly say so. By the way, how did you get your result for $N$? Did you also find $\omega$ first? Also, I wonder what happens to the component of $\vec{N}$ which acts in the direction of the rod ($N\cos\theta$)... it seems to be absorbed by the rod.

Comment: Yes first I found $\omega$. It is same as what you did..How is that possible to absorbed component of $\vec{N}$ by the rod?

Comment: @noname The first answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556549/44978) confirms that the center of mass won't move horizontally. Anyway, $\vec{N}$ acts purely upwards (since the table is smooth) and when we calculate the torque we take the cross product which introduces the $\sin\theta$ term.

Comment: Yes. thank you very much for supporting..